# Array assignment in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

What is the difference between

```
myArr1 => \@existingarray
```

and

```
myArr2 => [
              @existingarray
          ]
```

I am assigning the `@existingarray` to a element in a hash map.

I mean what exactly internally happens. Is it that for the first one,  it points to the same array and for the second array it creates a new array with the elements in the `@existingarray`

Thanks in advance

Comment: They both give syntax errors :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the first one takes a reference, the second one does a copy and then takes a reference.

`[ ... ]` is the anonymous array constructor, and turns the list inside into an arrayref.

So with `@a = 1, 2, 3`,

```
[ @a ]
```

is the same as

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

(the array is flattened to a list) or

```
do {
  my @b = @a;
  \@b;
}
```

In effect, the elements get copied.

Also,

```
my ($ref1, $ref2) = (\@a, [@a]);
print "$ref1 and $ref2 are " . ($ref1 eq $ref2 ? "equal" : "not equal") . "\n";
```

would confirm that they are *not* the same. And if we do

```
$ref1->[0] = 'a';
$ref2->[0] = 'b';
```

then `$a[0]` would equal `a` and *not* `b`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
perl -e 'my @a=(1); my $ra=\@a; my $rca=[@a]; $ra->[0]=2; print @a, @{$ra}, @{$rca};'
221
```

to see that your assumption that [@existingarray] creates a reference to a copy of @existingarray is correct (and that `myArray*` isn't Perl).

WRT amon's revising my `perl -e "..."` (fails under bash) to `perl -e '...'` (fails under cmd.exe): Use the quotes that work for your shell.

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets make a reference to a new array with a copy of what's in @existingarray at the time of the assignment.